# In Terraform, get first matching file name in current path

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Is it possible in terraform to retrieve the first file with a name matching some regex in either the current directory, or any parent directory?

For example, I would want it to first check for `config.json` in the current directory. If it exists, it stops. If it doesn't, it checks for `../config.json`, then `../../config.json`, etc.

```
.
├── directory1
│   ├── subdirectory1
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── config.json
└── directory2
    └── config.json
```

In this example, it should return `directory1/config.json`. I would then want to use [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsondecode) to parse some value in this configuration file and assign it to a variable.

The closest functionality I've seen to this is [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset), but I don't think it can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you have the right idea. You could use your regex with `fileset` to return a list of all matches, and then return the first element from the list assuming it meets the criteria you want. The return behavior seems to be parent directory versus child, and normal alphanumeric sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I acutally did something similar quite recently.

Select the first file of a chain, which is present:

```
output "first_match" {
    value = try(
            tolist(fileset(path.module, "file1"))[0], 
            tolist(fileset(path.module, "folder/file2"))[0], 
            tolist(fileset(path.module, "folder/folder/file3"))[0], 
            "default if nothing matches")
}
```